# AJAX login cannot map username - always NULL

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to migrate from normal login form to AJAX.Everything works perfectly without ajax but when I tried to implement it, but one error occurred - `The key "_username" must be a string, "NULL" given`.Why does that happen?

I believe that username cannot be mapped, but why? The AJAX request is properly set up and it sends _username and _password.I tried to convert them into strings, but nothing changed.

Login form:

```
<form id="loginForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control inner-blue-shadow" id="username" name="_username" placeholder="Username"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control inner-blue-shadow" id="password" name="_password" placeholder="Password"/>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" id="loginButton">Log in</button></div>
</form>
```

AJAX:

```
$('#loginForm ').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const form = $("#loginForm");
    const username = $('#username').val();
    const password = $('#password').val();
    axios
        .post('{{path('login')}}', {
            _username: username,
            _password: password
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error.data);
        });

    return false;
});
```

Security.yaml

```
form_login:
    login_path:  login
    check_path:  login
    success_handler: authentication_handler
    failure_handler: authentication_handler
```

The handler:

```
namespace AppBundle\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\DisabledException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;

class AuthenticationHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface, AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
{
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        return new Response("Some success response...");
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        var_dump($exception);
        if ($exception instanceof DisabledException) {
            return new JsonResponse([
               'message' => 'The account is disabled.'
            ]);
        } else {
            return new JsonResponse([
               'message' => 'Password or username is incorrect.'
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Login controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 * @return RedirectResponse|Response
 */
public function login()
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if($user) {
        $userRoles = $user->getRoles();
        if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
            if(in_array(Role::ROLE_STUDENT, $userRoles)) {
                return $this->redirectToRoute('dashboard_student_home');
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->render('security/login.html.twig');
}
```

Comment: Can you share the login action in controller?

Comment: Sure.I've updated the post.

Comment: Where exactly do you use `_username`? I expected it as a parameter in the login action.

Comment: Are you certain that you have only one element on the page with  `id="username"`? Ids have to be unique. If you have more than one element with this id, your jquery could be pulling the empty value from the other element instead of the one you intend. What do you get if you do `console.log(username, password);` right after your constants?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem is that as a data I had to pass the whole form:

```
const form = document.getElementById("loginForm");
const data = new FormData(form);
axios.post('{{path('login')}}', data);
```

This way everything is submitted properly - username, password and even CSRF.